# Ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04 Wake on lan doesn't work while 12.04 works

Tags: wakeonlan

I had 12.04. Recently I upgraded it to 14.04. Before upgrade I made a full hdd copy to very same hdd model(both bought at the same time).
In 12.04 wake on lan works if I do 
`sudo pm-hibernate`
or if I in UI from desktop select "Shutdown".

I upgraded a full HDD copy of 12.04 to 14.04. Use same hardware and wake on lan doesn't work. If I do same steps.

I tried `sudo ethtool -s enp2s0 wol g` (enp2s0 is a network interface name), but it was previously in g. So no effect.

I have a fresh installation of 16.04.1 and I was able to wake it only once after I set `NETDOWN=no`  in `/etc/default/halt`, but it did not work after I wanted to verify it once again.

Added at the end of `/etc/network/interfaces` next 6 lines

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.12
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        up ethtool s enp2s0 wol g
```

And did `sudo pm-hibernate` and was not able to wake up. Only once it worked when I logged in and in UI locally clicked shutdown. After that tried few times and no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note I already had wakeonlan enabled in the bios and through ethtool. It stopped working at some point for me after doing dist-upgrades.

I was able to get it to work for 17.04 by:

1) Installing the tlp package with:

```
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

2) Changing the line in "/etc/default/tlp" that says

```
WOL_DISABLE=Y
```

To

```
WOL_DISABLE=N
```

3) After shutting down the computer it was able to be started with WOL. I test this on two different machines and it worked on both.

---

After running this solution for a while, I found an unintended side effect where some of my USB devices were losing power. I ended up disabling the USB autosuspend feature of tlp by changing the line in "/etc/default/tlp" that says

```
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
```

To

```
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0
```

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Many thanks, for your answer. It really helped me and now it works in 16.04